# Define the complexity of minimum sub sum code

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, performance

The code works and does exactly what I would expect it to, but it's a bit difficult for me to dictate the complexity of it.

```
public static int smallestSubSum(int arr[], int x){
        int sum = 0, left = 0;
        int len = arr.length+1;

        for (int right = 0; right < arr.length; right++){
            sum += arr[right];
            while (sum > x && left <= right){
                len = Math.min(len, right-left + 1);
                sum -= arr[left];
                left++;
            }
        }

        if (len == arr.length+1) 
            return -1;
        return len;
    }
```

Since we go over each element in the array, the complexity so far is O(n) where n is the length of the array, it's just the while inside there that I can't judge if it's negligible or not. The worst case scenario for it is to be called only at the last element, where it goes over an additional n iterations. Does that mean the code is still in the complexity O(n)?

Comment: The total number of calls to the inner loop is no more than n, since you don't reset 'left' to 0. So I think it is O(n+n) = O(n)

Comment: What is `n`? Your question is ambiguous since the function has two inputs, so the argument function of the O must be dyadic. Anyway, the time complexity is linear in the size of the input array.

Comment: Absolutely right, I'm editing. n is the length of the array.